# Is there a noticeable effect when changing "search.smartCase" from true to false or vice versa

Tags: visual-studio-code

As I understand Visual Studio Code's documentation, the setting of `"search.smartCase"` influences whether Visual Studo Code searches case sensitively or case insensitively. I understand the documentation such that the search is case-insensive if `"search.smartCase"` is set to `true` *and* I search for a term using lower case letters only. If set to `true` but searching for a term that contains uppercase letters, the search is case sensitive.

However, I can set `"search.smartCase"` to both, `true` and `false`, and am unable to detect a noticeable effect of this setting. In both cases, the case sensitivity is only determined whether I explicitly search case sensitively or insensitively (`alt+c`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting seems to apply when you use a Search Editor window, rather than regular search.

For example, I tested with a plain text file containing the word "Stackoverflow" spelt three different ways (`Stackoverflow`, `stackoverflow` and `stackOverflow`) with the setting set to true.  If I search all lowercase, it finds all three instances, but if I specify a capital letter, it only finds the ones that match:

[image: smart case]